# How to just check if the mongodb .find returns something or not so true or false

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

How to find out if the `.find` returns something or not? I'm trying to make it so if it returns nothing, it saves a schema with an auth token (check 2), and if it returns something it does check 3. But everytime, even when I do not have a schema with my `discordId` in the database it logs `check 3` and `check 1` but never `check 2`.

```js
let discordId = message.author.id;
const discordIdCheck = authSchema.find({
  discordId: discordId,
});
console.log('check 1');
if (discordIdCheck.count() < 1) {
  function getAuthToken() {
    var letters =
      '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!.#&';
    var authTokenStart = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      authTokenStart += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
    }
    return authTokenStart;
  }

  const authToken = getAuthToken();

  const auth = {
    discordId: discordId,
    authToken: authToken,
  };
  console.log('check 2');
  message.author.send('Okay, your auth token is: ' + authToken);
  console.log(authToken);
  new authSchema(auth).save();
} else {
  message.channel.send(
    'You already have an auth token. use !token to make me send it to you in your direct messages',
  );
  console.log('Check 3 ');
}
```

Comment: Did you check the database directly to verify that `authSchema` is empty?

Comment: what do you mean chec kit directly? authSchema is equal to require('auth-schema.js') if you want that

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti , didnt mention you in reply*

Comment: Your logic looks OK; first principles suggests that `discordId` does in fact exist which is why you keep getting `Check 3`.

Comment: Aren't `find` and `count` both async functions in Mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `length` value to check the length of the `find()` result like:

```js
const discordIdCheck = await authSchema.find({
  discordId: discordId,
});

if(discordIdCheck.length <= 0) console.log("0 found")
```

Comment: It didn't work, .length returned undefined

Comment: Hmm, I tried this myself, and even if there were no finds it would return 0, could you show us `authSchema`?

Comment: Alright, I'm not currently at my PC but once I get back ill edit the post and show the variable authSchema and the auth-Schema.js and my code when using discordIdCheck.length.

Comment: Sorry. I tried it with an await on the discordIdCheck and wrapped it in an async function. It works now. Thanks!